# PHP Environment Variables

Tags: php, windows

I'm not sure why I'm still getting the PHP is not recognized as an internal or external command error. Here's my environment variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec MyWinLocker\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec MyWinLocker\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin; C:\PHP\;
```

My PHP.exe is located in "C:\PHP\", so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. :/

Comment: If you're running it from Command Prompt, did you close the window and start another one after you added the environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Windows machine to verify this, but I am pretty sure you cannot have spaces after the `;` delimiters.  Remove the space before `C:\PHP`, and it may be harmless, but also remove the trailing `\`.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\;...snip...;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;C:\PHP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

Depending on how you are launching PHP, you might need to log out of Windows and back in to propagate the new `%PATH%` through your environment, though I doubt that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try only: C:\PHP (Without the last '\'). After this save the changes, restart your computer and write this on your cmd

```
php -v
```

to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did in fact have to restart my computer for the changes to work. Also, you can't have a space after the semi-colon for anyone else who encounters this problem.